# Persistent data using ngResouce

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory like this:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('RepositoriesService', RepositoriesService);

function RepositoriesService($resource) {

  var persistentData = null;

  var data = $resource('http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
    query: { isArray: false }
  });

  return data;

}
```

In my controller, I can get the data like this:

```
RepositoriesService.query();
```

Now, I want persistent data in the factory. So the first time the query is made, the data returned should save to the `persistentData` variable. Subsequent `query` requests to the factory should return  the `persistentData` value rather than making a new API request for data. I know how to do this easily with `$http` but is it possible with `ngResource`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) you can use the `cache` option:

> cache – {boolean|Cache} – If true, a default $http cache will be used to cache the GET request, otherwise if a cache instance built with $cacheFactory, this cache will be used for caching.

To cache the `query` requests in your case:

```
  var data = $resource('http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
    update: { method: 'PUT' },
    query: { isArray: false, cache: true }
  });
```

**EDIT:**
To have a better control over the cache, pass your own `cache` object built with the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) service:

```
// now you can use this object in your service
// to control the cache behaviour, like clean it after a while
var myCache = $cacheFactory('RepositoryService');

var data = $resource('http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
  update: { method: 'PUT' },
  query: { isArray: false, cache: myCache }
});
```

Comment: Interesting. How would I set a cache time specific to this call?

Comment: @Coop, There is no such option to do it for you. You'll have to handle the cache expiration using the `$cacheFactory` by yourself. See the updated answer for details.